# An integrable function, but not necessarily a continuous one, is continuous when integrated.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $f:\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function, but not necessarily continuous, with the property that $0\leq f(s)\leq 1$. Let $g:\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function given by:
$$
g(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(s)\,ds.
$$
Prove that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ might prove fruitful. Have you tried that?

Comment: I would start by expressing $g(t)-g(u)$ in terms of an integral of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

This proof is for Riemann integrable function, i.e. bounded.

$g(t_2)-g(t_1)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(s)ds$.  Since $|f(s)|\le M$, $|g(t_2)-g(t_1)|\le M(t_2-t_1)$.  For any $\epsilon$, let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{M}$.  So that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is a $\delta$ where $|t_2-t_1|\lt \delta$,  $|g(t_2)-g(t_1)|\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't think I can use FTC since the function $f$ isn't necessarily continuous. Please correct me if I'm wrong. (I at least think you're using the FTC in the first line).

Comment: @VictorH No, that is not the FTC. This is the additivity of integral limits (or whatever it is called). The precise statement is that if $a\leq c \leq b$ and $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ is a Riemann-integrable function then $f$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$ and $\int_a^c f + \int_c^b f = \int_a^b f$. Also, we make the convention that $\int_b^a f = - \int_a^b f$. So, in this answer, $ g(t_2) - g(t_1) = \int_0^{t_2} f - \int_0^{t_1}f = \int_0^{t_2}f + \int_{t_1}^0 f = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} f$

Answer (score 1):

We shall solve this by the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Let $t>t_0$. Then, we have -
$$|g(t)-g(t_0)| = \left|\int_{t_0}^tf(s)ds\right|$$
Now, as $0<f(s)<1$, $|f(s)|<1$, and we get - 
$$\left|\int_{t_0}^tf(s)ds\right| \le \int_{t_0}^t|f(s)|ds\le |t-t_0|$$
Thus, $|g(t)-g(t_0)|\le|t-t_0|$, and continuity follows by taking $\delta = \epsilon$ in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: Are you using FTC in the first equation?